# Entity Framework Core filter by an entity's collection

Tags: linq, filter, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to retrieve all entities based on data in their nested collection.
I have a Family and an Adult object, and a DbContext:

```
    public class Family {
        // other properties
        public List<Adult> Adults { get; set; }
        public List<Child> Children{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        // other properties
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string HairColor { get; set; }
    }

    public class FamilyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Family> Families { get; set; }
        // other stuff..
    }
```

Now, I would like to retrieve all Families, where at least one Adult has red hair.
My best guess is this:

```
    var result = ctx.Families.
        Include(family => family.Adults.Where(adult => adult.HairColor.Equals("Red"))).
        Where(family => family.Adults.Count>0).
        ToList();
```

When debugging, I can see that after the Include, I have all my Families, but only Adults with red hair is loaded. All other families have just 0 Adults.

So I thought I could then just filter based on the number of Adults loaded. But that's not working. It seems to just load all adults when needing them here, and the end result is all existing Family entities.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for hours. And immediately after posting, I found this:

```
var result = ctx.Families.
   Where(family => family.Adults.Any(adult => adult.HairColor.Equals("Red"))).
   ToList()
```